# Drawing a canvas (with drawImage) into another not working

Tags: canvas, drawimage

I'm trying to make a game where all enemies are drawn into a single canvas (`ctxEnemy`), but I'm having some difficulties making them face different positions, since using the rotate canvas function it will rotate all of them at the same time.

My idea to sort this out was to actually draw them in an auxiliary canvas, rotate that canvas, and only then draw it into the main canvas. That would be just fine if `drawImage()` wasn't crashing everything...

I've been able to use `ctxEnemy.drawImage(ctxAux,0,0)` on the first lines of the code for testing, but whenever I place it within any drawing function, it stops working.

QUESTION: can someone explain me why `drawImage()` is not working, or maybe even giving me another simpler solution to my problem?

```
Enemy.prototype.draw = function(){
    ctxAux.clearRect(0,0,gameWidth,gameHeight);
    ctxAux.drawImage(imgSprite,this.srcX,this.srcY,this.width,this.height,this.drawX,this.drawY,this.width,this.height);
    //ctxAux.rotate(some angle);
    ctxEnemy.drawImage(ctxAux,0,0);
}
```

Comment: We need to see more code to determine the problem. Please post the class for your enemy (the relevant parts if very long), and how you set of the aux canvas. A fiddle can do wonders as well.

Answer (score 1):

A Demo using this simple spritsheet (2 sprites):  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/ZJunX/

[image]

First define where each of your individual sprites are on your spritesheet:

```
var sprites={
    shipOff:{x:0,y:0,w:90,h:90},
    shipOn:{x:90,y:0,w:90,h:90},
}
```

If you want to rotate your enemy around its centerpoint, then this function will draw your enemy:

```
function drawEnemy(spritename,drawCenterX,drawCenterY,radianAngle){

    // get the desired sprite info from sprites[]
    var sprite=sprites[spritename];

    // save the unrotated context state
    ctx.save();

    // translate to the desired rotation point
    ctx.translate(drawCenterX,drawCenterY);

    // rotate by the desired angle
    ctx.rotate(radianAngle);

    // clip this desired sprite from the spritesheet and 
    // draw it on the canvas
    ctx.drawImage(spritesheet,
        sprite.x,sprite.y,sprite.w,sprite.h,
        -sprite.w/2,-sprite.h/2,sprite.w,sprite.h
    );

    // restore the context to its unrotated state
    ctx.restore();
}
```

Function arguments:

- spritename is a name from your sprites object (eg "shipOn")
- drawCenterX/drawCenterY is where on the canvas your enemy will be drawn (the center of the enemy sprite image will be at drawCenterX/drawCenterY)
- radianAngle is the angle you want the sprite to be rotated